# Dockerized Rails 7+Puma SSL fails with 'PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, ssl

I'm trying to `docker`ize a `rails 7` app using the default `puma` server with `ssl` enabled using a self-signed cert. Launching the app natively works as expected.

When running as a container, I get a 'PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR' error in Firefox. Testing with other browsers results in 'This site can'be reached. localhost unexepectedly closed the connection'.

`docker run` command: `docker run --rm -it -p 3000:3000 my-app-image`

`Dockerfile` CMD: `CMD [ "rails", "s" ]`

Troubleshooting steps:

1. Machine reboot
2. Update Docker
3. Map host port 443 to container port 3000
4. `$RAILS_ENV` both as development and production
5. Variations of rails command in docker file:

   1. `CMD [ "bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0" ]`
   2. `CMD [ "rails", "s", "-b", "127.0.0.1" ]`
   3. `CMD [ "rails", "s", "-u", "puma", "-b", "'ssl://127.0.0.1/?key=server.key&cert=server.crt&verify_mode=none'" ]`

**config/application.rb**

```
...
# Enable SSL
config.force_ssl = true
...
```

**config/puma.rb**

```
...
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

# SSL Configuration
localhost_key = 'server.key'
localhost_crt = 'server.crt'

ssl_bind 'localhost', 3000, {
  key: localhost_key,
  cert: localhost_crt,
  verify_mode: 'none'
}
...
```

Since it works when run natively, I think the issue lies with either `docker` or `puma`, but I'm not sure what it could be or how to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was binding the ssl port in the `puma.rb` config file to localhost, which isn't available outside of the running container.

Changing:

`ssl_bind 'localhost', 3000, {`

To:

`ssl_bind '0.0.0.0', 3000, {`

resolved the issue.